# none of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Пытаюсь получить в приложении Android широту и долготу, но не получается даже запустить GPS. При попытки скомпилировать проект, получаю следующую ошибку: **none of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied** и подчеркивает красной линией именно **requestLocationUpdates**.

Сам код:

```js
    private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null

val locationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                te.append("n " + location.longitude + " " + location.latitude)
            }

            fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}

            fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}

            fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener)
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. Проблема заключалась в том, что было импортировано не то что нужно. Следует заменить `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` на `import android.location.LocationListener`. Дополнительно следует поменять `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener)` на `locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0.toFloat(), locationListener)`.